# Crawlers that generate sitemaps only find one page on my site despite being allowed to crawl by robots.txt

Tags: xml, sitemap

Having a real problem here, I've tried lots of services to sort this including http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ as well as software and a PHP script.

Basically my domain is http://gamingdeluxe.co.uk/

Whenever I run it through a sitemap generator it ONLY finds that 1 page, and doesn't follow any of the links.

However robots.txt is setup as

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

so that shouldn't be a problem?

I found a Java crawler called DRKSpiderJava and it crawled my site sucessfuly—shame no export to .xml feature. so they seem to be crawlable.

Any ideas why I cant generate one?

Comment: worked for me just fine.

Comment: I've no idea what happened. I just kept trying and trying and then suddenly one of the sites worked, then all the others did :s very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by trying making your site any "w3c norm-compliant".

Use some validation engine (like http://validator.w3.org/check) to ensure your site is easily parsable without errors...

After trying to parse your home page, I see some critical errors like:

- Unable to Determine Parse Mode!,
- No DOCTYPE found, and unknown root element. Aborting validation.

...and a lot of other (16 errors mentioned my w3.org validator)

Maybe that is why no standard external parsers can do the job for you...

Comment: again not sure what happened, I just loaded the website through w3 and it came out as "Passed! 1 Warning" - and that was the html5 standards are not 100% reliable at the moment.